# Fan Speed in Macbook running Linux

Tags: linux, laptop

I am currently running arch on an older generation macbook; 2009 with a core2duo processor.

One of the common issues with the machine is that it runs hot (70-90 while browsing and playing videos on youtube). One quick hack that I have been adopting is to increase the fan speed when things go out of hand.

This is a little clumsy, but it works.

```
echo "speed" > /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/fan1_min
```

Here "speed" is from 2000..6000.

To make things easy, I wrote a simple python script that increases the fan-speed based on the temperature. Unfortunately, I can't seem to set write permissions for these files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/nwjlyons/fdb269f8f9cb40798e83) will help you.

Comment: @torchhound I am doing something very similar, but I want to run it as a regular user. Either a script running in the background or manually controlling it through keyboard. ( for feedback, I am using the xfce temperature applet which shows cpu temp and fan speed)

Comment: Known problem. The firmware is broken on those Macs, fan control must be done in software. Some distros ship a macfanctld daemon for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `/sys` filesystem contains information set by the kernel, mostly for the benefit of udev, along with some knobs for userspace to set some options. It is not a storage-backed filesystem, and as such you cannot make arbitrary changes, like changing file permissions.

If you want to control some knobs from a non-root process, I can see two options:

1. Write a daemon which runs as root and exports an API that non-root processes can talk to (e.g., using dbus). The non-root process sends a command to set the fan speed; the root process does some permissions- and sanity checking and performs the change.
2. Rather than a daemon, use something like `sudo` to gain the necessary privileges. You'll still need to do those same checks, but can dispense with the need to have yet another process run as root *all* the time.